# SPARQL query for all sameAs

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl, dbpedia

I want to take all objects with the relation `owl:sameAs` with my object `Berlin`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your attempts, and tell us what's not working about them.  Stack Overflow isn't a code factory.

Comment: Based on [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373590/sparql-query-for-all-sameas#comment37715684_24376555): "I got my mistake :) i forgot to put PREDIX :) –  TNeykov", this question should be closed as a typographical error … resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite simple:

```
PREFIX owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?obj WHERE {
    dbpedia:Berlin (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?obj
}
```

***How it works:***
This is going to select all `?obj` for which there is any triple such as:

```
subject           predicate     object
dbpedia:Berlin    owl:sameAs    ?obj
```

or:

```
subject           predicate     object
?obj              owl:sameAs    dbpedia:Berlin
```

Comment: This won't actually get everything that's the same as Berlin, though.  owl:sameAs is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  The pattern should really be `dbpedia:Berlin (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?obj`.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool, I never paid attention to that. Thank you @JoshuaTaylor :)

Comment: I got my mistake  :) i forgot to put PREDIX :)

Comment: @TNeykov You should close your question then, since "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. … this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."  Someone else who forgets an owl prefix isn't likely to find this question based on its title or any code in your question, so it's not helpful to other users.