# How do I query DBPedia to obtain all owl:sameAs links?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a direct link to a DBPedia page (e.g. [Argentina](http://dbpedia.org/page/Argentina)) and I'd like to retrieve some or all links with the owl:sameAs label (e.g. [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q414), [freebase](http://www.freebase.com/m/0jgd), etc.)

All the tutorials that I've read focus on retrieving group of object with particular features (e.g., French films).

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373590/sparql-query-for-all-sameas) but it just returns one result instead of the entire list of owl:sameAs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns what you're looking for:

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?obj WHERE {
    dbpedia:Argentina (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs) ?obj
}
```

Note that the URI of the resource is actually http://dbpedia.org/resource/Argentina, not page/Argentina.  When you put the first URI into a web browser, though, you get redirected to the latter.  Be sure to use the former in your query (or just use the prefix **dbpedia:**).

Comment: @ciekawy DBpedia changed their default prices a while back, so some queries might not work anymore. It's not that it doesn't return anything, but that it says "Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia'". If you change the dbpedia: to dbr: (I think) this should be fine.

Comment: actually now all works ok! Not sure what was wrong before - it's possible the service was down or so.